# Navigating from TabbedPage to ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

I have a TabbedPage with three tabs which is my main page. In one of the tabs I have a ListView and on clicking on the Item in ListView I want to navigate to a new Page.

I can navigate to the new page but the page is displayed within the tab. I do not want the page to be within the tab and should take be opened a new page taking the whole screen.

This is my listView itemSelected method within one of the tabs.

How can I make the DocketDetail page take the entire screen.

I have tried making it the 'MainPage' which

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DocketDetail());
```

But doing this I could not go back to the TabbedPage.

Please suggest

```
  lvLiveDockets.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Item DeSelected", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Ok");
                    return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Item Selected", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Ok");
                    this.Navigation.PushAsync(new DocketDetail());
                }

                //((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; //uncomment line if you want to disable the visual selection state.
            };
```

My App.Xaml.cs

```
  MainPage = new TabbedPage
            {
                Children =
                {
                    new NavigationPage(new PendingDockets())
                    {
                        Title = "Pending Dockets",
                        Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_about.png",null,null)
                    },
                    new NavigationPage(new LiveDockets())
                    {
                        Title = "Live Dockets",
                        Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_about.png",null,null)
                    },
                    new NavigationPage(new ArchiveDockets())
                    {
                        Title = "Archive Dockets",
                        Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_about.png",null,null)
                    },
                }
            };`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the TabbedPage inside a Navigation Stack (I think as Root page)

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Tabpage());
```

when you select yout item in listview, you should push a new page

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new DocketDetail());
```

I hope to have understand your problem

```
  lvLiveDockets.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Item DeSelected", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Ok");
                    return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Item Selected", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Ok");
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new DocketDetail();
                }

                //((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; //uncomment line if you want to disable the visual selection state.
            };
```

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with how my App.xaml.cs looks like with TabbedPage set as MainPage. How do I change it to what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `App.cs` could be changed to this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPage()
        {
            Children =
            {
                new PendingDockets()
                {
                    Title = "Pending Dockets",
                    Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_about.png",null,null)
                },
                new LiveDockets()
                {
                    Title = "Live Dockets",
                    Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_about.png",null,null)
                },
                new ArchiveDockets()
                {
                    Title = "Archive Dockets",
                    Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_about.png",null,null)
                },
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, I have done that already and I can navigate to the DocketDetails page. but on that page on the top navigation bar I do not get the back arrow to go back to the previous view as it is a new page.

Comment: @Alessandro is correct, I can show you how to put it in your code though.

Comment: Basically, the MainPage should be a NavigationPage containing your TabbedPage.  The children of the TabbedPage should be your different ContentPages without the individual NavigationPages

Comment: I just tried that I placed the Tabbed page within the NavigationPage in App.xaml '  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPage
            {
                Children =
                {' AND RUN IT, it displays the DocketDetail page within the tab

Comment: Only when I use 'App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DocketDetail());' it goes to a complete new screen without tabs

Comment: Do you think this is the behaviour because if you see my App.xaml within the tabbedPage i have three NavigationPages that is why the new page is opening within this NavigationPage. Any idea how to get over it?

Comment: If you are creating the Children of the TabbedPage in your c# code behind you should not do it in your xaml

Comment: I am only creating the children for tabbedpage in App.xaml. not anywhere else

Comment: Sorry I mean App.Xaml.cs.

Comment: Yes, try getting rid of the three inner NavigationPages

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?  It is generally considered bad practice and goes against what users have come to expect in an app with tabs.  The way you had it set up before is the recommended way to do a TabbedPage

Comment: I want to have tabbs on the main page . and in each tab has list views. so when a list item is clicked i want to show the full details of the list item. If the list item is populated within the tab it looses space. I was just doing some research and having the new DocketDetails content page open as a Dialog( Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DocketDetail());). By doing this I can go back to the list view.

Comment: I just saw an article that mentioned that too.  That is probably the only way to accomplish what you are trying to do in Forms.  However, I'd still advise to keep it all in the tabs and just have a little less room.  Sorry I wasn't much help